# Does World of Warcraft benefit from AMD CrossFireX or nVidia SLI?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, technical-issues

I am now running two Radeon HD 6850's in CrossFireX configuration (Thanks to Stack Exchange and the LoL contest!). Does World of Warcraft support Crossfire GPU's in the sense that;

- Will there be any stability issues introduced from this setup?
- Will there be any noticeable improvement in graphical performance?

There is a lot of discussion for both sides of this issue, so reputable testing or official sources would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

WoW **doesn't support crossfire or SLI**. In fact, most MMOs don't support it.

The code just is not optimized for it and as a result, **things actually run worse**. Even if they took the time to support Crossfire and SLI, I don't believe performance would increase much.

WoW is old game and not graphic intensive, but rather CPU and memory intensive due to its constant expansion of code,players...

[Perfomance test](http://www.techpowerup.com/reviews/ATI/Radeon_HD_6870_CrossFire/18.html)

@Doomsknight : Simply put wow models are just too low on polygons(detail) and they can run perfectly fine on old graphic cards,increasing performance from 50FPS to 150FPS is only statistic you won't notice much past 25FPS in 3rd person online game if they want to use the gained power they need new models for game and that is making completely new game...which they are doing with titan.And only thing why game is CPU intensive is because they have to keep their subscribers interested in game by adding more and more content without actually making a new game.

Comment: And why cant this new code be directed towards the Graphics card instead? If they decided to improve it, they should focus on using the power of the graphics cards, not the CPU since one hugely overpowers the other.

Comment: Because most graphics cards are only capable of running graphics related calculations, and requiring one with GPGPU features would massively increase system requirements for a game which considers its ability to run on about anything a major plus point. Plus, even on cards with GPGPU features, code needs to be written specially for them, which is rather complex. And finally, unless the code is easy to parralelise, there may be no benefit to running it on a GPU.